# How to join items from same column using pandas in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
print(dfs["Categorias"])
```

I'm getting this:

```
0                         wordpress, criação de sites
1                                    criação de sites
2             e-commerce, criação de sites, wordpress
3                           marketing digital, vendas
```

How can I remove repeated items and join the unique values in list?

Thank you

Comment: And how exactly do you want the result to look?

Comment: What have you tried already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like that:

Split each row into a list and explode this list into rows then get unique values of the column.

```
>>> df['Categorias'].str.split(r',\s+').explode().unique().tolist()
['wordpress', 'criação de sites', 'e-commerce', 'marketing digital', 'vendas']
```

Step by step:

```
>>> df = df['Categorias'].str.split(r',\s+')
0
0                [wordpress, criação de sites]
1                           [criação de sites]
2    [e-commerce, criação de sites, wordpress]
3                  [marketing digital, vendas]
Name: Categorias, dtype: object

>>> df = df.explode()
0
0            wordpress
0     criação de sites
1     criação de sites
2           e-commerce
2     criação de sites
2            wordpress
3    marketing digital
3               vendas
Name: Categorias, dtype: object

>>> df.unique().tolist()
['wordpress', 'criação de sites', 'e-commerce', 'marketing digital', 'vendas']
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what the code does? It looks interesting.

Comment: @AshokArora. I updated my answer with some explanation and a step-by-step commands.

Answer (score 1):

You could use sets and `itertools.chain`:

```
from itertools import chain
set(chain(*df['Categorias'].str.split(',\s+')))
```

Output:

```
{'criação de sites', 'e-commerce', 'marketing digital', 'vendas', 'wordpress'}
```

Optionally, as list:

```
>>> list(set(chain(*df['Categorias'].str.split(',\s+'))))
['criação de sites', 'e-commerce', 'marketing digital', 'vendas', 'wordpress']
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to convert the dataframe column to a list, remove duplicates using a set and then join them using string operations.

```py
>>> ', '.join(set(df['Categorias'].str.split(', ').explode().tolist()))
```